# Java FX looping through Anchor pane to get CheckBox name and if selected

Tags: javafx, java-8, fxml

I have an Anchorpane which will have up to 20+ check boxes on it. I want to write a loop to get the name of each check box and if it is selected.

I have this working code so far

```
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

@FXML
private AnchorPane lootAnchorPane;

ObservableList<Node> children = lootAnchorPane.getChildren();
            for (Node child : children) {
                System.out.println(child.getId());
            }
```

This prints the id's well enough but I am not able to use `child.getText()` or `child.isSelected()`. As far as i understand the Checkbox classes are returned. I think it has something to do with the `@FXML` annotation. But im not sure how to implement this inside a for loop?

Comment: If you know all the children are Checkboxes cast the node to checkbox.

Comment: If not all the nodes are CheckBoxes, use `if(instanceof CheckBox)` in the loop. Then cast those nodes to CheckBox.

Comment: this worked, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

The asker has indicated that this question has already been answered by the kind commenter Sedrick. To try and make it as clear as possible to anyone viewing this post afterwards, I am posting a formal answer with a code example.

To use CheckBox methods with Node objects you have to first make sure the Node is an instance of a CheckBox. Use `if (child instanceOf Node)` to do so. If they are, it is safe to cast them to CheckBox type, and you can then use CheckBox methods with them.

```
ObservableList<Node> children = lootAnchorPane.getChildren();

for (Node child : children) {

   // check if Node is an instance of CheckBox.
   if (child instanceOf CheckBox) {

      // Cast child Node to CheckBox
      CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) child;

      // --- do stuff with the CheckBox object.
   }
}
```